# How to make to element draggable when one element is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use draggble jquery-ui library.

I have two elements draggable div and red rectangle.

```js
$("#toolbarArea").draggable();
```

```css
.toolbarArea {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 30px;
  width: 400px;
}

.exosphere {
  border: solid 1px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#toolbarTitle {
  cursor: all-scroll;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

#rslt {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="toolbarArea" class="toolbarArea exosphere" data-Owner="geomind" data-Date="11/2016">

  <span id="toolbarTitle" width="15px" height="15px" class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-arrows" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>

  <iframe id="frTools" style="width:90%;height:25px;overflow: hidden;"></iframe></div>
<div id="rslt"></div>
```

I need to make red rectangle repeat toolbarArea position when it dragged.

I dont want to put red rectangle inside toolbarArea div.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood it correctly, you are trying to move the red rectangle and the toolbar simultaniously?

Then how about wrapping the whole HTML block into another ?

```
<div id="newId">


<div id="toolbarArea" class="toolbarArea exosphere" data-Owner="geomind" data-Date="11/2016"> 

   <span id="toolbarTitle" width="15px" height="15px" class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-arrows" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>

        <iframe id="frTools" style="width:90%;height:25px;overflow: hidden;"></iframe>

                </div>

            <div id="rslt"></div>
            </div>
```

You then change JS to:

```
$( "#newId" ).draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you, you want to move the redsquare as the toolbar is moved?

In that case you can use a custom jQuery function similar to [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/12/jQuery-CSS-Property-Monitoring-Plugin-updated). By using the function described in that blogpost, you can watch for when an element is moved. Each time it is moved, you can update another element with those coordinates by doing this:

```
$('#rlst').offset($('#toolbarArea').offset());
```

It won't be perfect, but I think this is the best way to keep two elements separate and have them move in conjunction with one another.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jQuery Draggable Events](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events) there you have, `start`, `stop` and `drag`.

Here an example:

```js
$("#toolbarArea").draggable({
  start: function() {
    $('#rslt').css('position', 'relative')
  },
  drag: function() {
    $('#rslt').offset($('#toolbarArea').offset());
  },
});
```

```css
.toolbarArea {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 30px;
  width: 400px;
}

.exosphere {
  border: solid 1px #333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

#toolbarTitle {
  cursor: all-scroll;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

#rslt {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="toolbarArea" class="toolbarArea exosphere" data-Owner="geomind" data-Date="11/2016">

  <span id="toolbarTitle" width="15px" height="15px" class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-arrows" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>

  <iframe id="frTools" style="width:90%;height:25px;overflow: hidden;"></iframe>

</div>

<div id="rslt"></div>
```

You for sure need to add some more logic, if you want keep the original relative distance between the elements.

But as you can see that solution is not optimal because you have some delay between the movement of the toolbar and the red box. But thats a limitation of jQuery ui.